# Panel datasets on nighttime lights

Tags: data-request

I am looking for panel data sets (either at the country-year or region-year level) on nighttime lights, preferrably with global coverage but at least covering the African continent.

Answer (score 0):

Found a potentially useful dataset here:
https://datainspace.org/index.php/regional-development-indicators-beta/.

Here is some information from the website:

Regional Development Indicators (Beta)

Regional Development Indicators (RDI) – Africa Version 0.1

Description:
Regional Development Indicators (RDI) for 5,968 African ADM2 regions and the years 1992-2015. In most instances, ADM2 regions refer to the second subnational level, such as counties or districts. However, a unique identifier of the ADM1 region (state, province) is also available and allows you to aggregate the data at a higher federal level.

The RDI contains information about: Landuse, Nighttime lights (luminosity), Conflict (battles, riots, violence against civilians, casualties), Mining activity, Road and port infrastructure, Oil and gas fields, Power plants

Answer (score 0):

Another potentially useful source is the blackmarbler package in R (https://github.com/cran/blackmarbler).